# Looking for a process to restore more than one job on job manager startup from the respective savepoints

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink (1.18) version for our Flink cluster. The job manager has been deployed in "Application mode" and we are looking for a process to restore multiple jobs (using their respective savepoint directories) when the job manager is started. Currently, we have the option to restore only one job while running "standalone-job.sh" using the --fromSavepoint and --allowNonRestoredState. However, we need a way to trigger multiple job executions via Java client.

Note: We are not using a Kubernetes native deployment, but we are using k8s standalone mode of deployment.

Expected process:

1. Before starting with the Flink/application image upgrade, trigger the savepoints for all the current running jobs.
2. Once the savepoints process completed for all jobs, will trigger the scale down of job manager and task manager instances.
3. Update the image version on the k8s deployment with the update application image.
4. After image version is updated, scale up the job manager and task manager.
5. We need a process to restore the previously running jobs from the savepoint dir and start all the jobs.